# ThreadLocals hard to use

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-local

I'm using `ThreadLocal` variables (through Clojure's vars, but the following is the same for plain `ThreadLocal`s in Java) and very often run into the issue that I can't be sure that a certain code path will be taken on the same thread or on another thread. For code under my control this is obviously not too big a problem, but for polymorphic third party code there's sometimes not even a way to statically determine whether it's safe to assume single threaded execution.

I tend to think this is a inherent issue with `ThreadLocal`s, but I'd like to hear some advise on how to use them in a safe way.

Comment: Where is your code and specific question?

Comment: Feel free to mark my question for community wiki if your bureaucratic instincts tell you that it is.

Comment: I don't understand the question, ThreadLocal s are to be used with multithreaded code. If you can assume single threaded execution use local variables...

Comment: I don't understand the question either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then don't use ThreadLocals! They are specifically for when you want a variable that's associated with a Thread, as if there were a `Map<Thread,T>`.

Comment: The answer is so simple! I’d +1 you but unfortunately I’m all out of votes for today.

Answer (score 0):

The typical use case (as far as I know) for a ThreadLocal is in a web application framework. An HTTP filter obtains a database connection on an incoming request, and stores the connection in a static ThreadLocal. All subsequent controllers needing the connection can  easily obtain it from the framework using a static call. When the response is returned, the same filter releases the connection again.